# Package.json with multiple entrypoints

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a library which was used as follows

```
import { Foo } from '@me/core';
const foo = new Foo();
```

The `package.json` of that library looks like

```
"name": "@me/core",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"license": "MIT",
...
```

With `dist/index.js` its entrypoint. Now, however, I would provide an import for NodeJs projects only and one for web projects. Ideally I would have something like this for NodeJs

```
import { Foo } from '@me/core/nodejs';
```

and if you're working on a web-project you could do

```
import { Foo } from '@me/core/web';
```

My understanding is that both `@me/core/nodejs` and `@me/core/web` will be different NPM packages this way, which is not what I want. I want it to be in 1 npm package.

I tried to changed the library's index.ts file, from

```
export * from './foo';
```

into

```
import * as nodejs from './nodejs';
import * as web from './web';

export { web, nodejs };
```

This actually works, but I have to use it now (in a NODEJS project) as follows

```
import { nodejs } from '@me/core';

const foo = new nodejs.Foo();
```

Is there maybe a way to import this such that I don't need the `nodejs` everytime?

As you can see I'm not so sure what I should do here so any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: Based on the suggestions by @Klaycon I see the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As you're using ECMAScript modules, please refer to node.js docs on [package entry points](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points):

> In a package’s package.json file, two fields can define entry points for a package: "main" and "exports". The "main" field is supported in all versions of Node.js, but its capabilities are limited: it only defines the main entry point of the package.
> The "exports" field provides an alternative to "main" where the package main entry point can be defined while also encapsulating the package, preventing any other entry points besides those defined in "exports". This encapsulation allows module authors to define a public interface for their package.

So, in your package.json, you could define `exports` like this:

```
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./nodejs": "./dist/nodejs",
    "./web": "./dist/web",
  }
```

Comment: This looks like the solution, except I cannot get it to work :( If the name of the package is **@me/core** should **core** then be part of the `exports` keys? If what you have is correct, then how should I import this? Like this **import { Foo } from '@me/core/nodejs';**? Right now it gives me the following error: **Cannot find module '@me/core/nodejs' or its corresponding type declarations**. Should I also define the type files somewhere maybe? Somehow it seems that the **exports** is completely ignored

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Whoops, I didn't quite realize that @me was the scope and the package name is `core` (correct me if that's incorrect). In that case omit `core` from the exports. I'll edit the answer to reflect.

Comment: I've added an image of the test project. The IDE on the left is the lib and on the right the app which implements it. Maybe you can see what I do wrong?

Comment: maybe this is an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079

Comment: I'm using typescript to compile my code, I'm getting the feeling it has to do with that

Comment: Damn, have to wait for that :( But thnx anyway, I'll mark you answer as the correct answer!

Comment: This is extremely useful for TS+Webpack as it makes it unnecessary to rename the file, which is tricky (if you build `index.server.ts` to `server.js`, you also have to rename your `.d.ts` file, which Webpack won't do for you). For instance, if you want "./server" to point to "./dist/index.server.js", you can do it very easily. You change the name of the export, not the name of your files.

Comment: Btw, found an article that allow bypassing this issue with TS using `typesVersions`: https://github.com/mozilla/glean.js/blob/main/glean/package.json and https://blog.mozilla.org/data/2021/04/07/this-week-in-glean-publishing-glean-js (be careful, I think the article has a typo in the config, check their package.json directly if you have a doubt)

Comment: I however have a negative side-effect from this: in the context of a Lerna monorepo, it behaves as if I was doing local import inadvertently. It doesn't treat "my-other-package/server" as an entry point during build, but instead as a local file of "my-other-package", thus bundling "my-package" into "my-other-package"...

Comment: Side question: I couldn't make this work with Jest moduleNameMapper, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420923/jest-modulenamemapper-and-npm-package-exports

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer, using the `exports` field, is one way to do it, but not the only way -- and as you've found, isn't currently supported by Typescript.

Look at the `@angular/material` package, which works similarly to what you have in mind.  In `@angular/material/package.json`, you've got a `module` field that points to an empty JS file, and a `typings` field that points to an empty `.d.ts` file.  But you've also got `@angular/material/button/package.json` which points (indirectly) to the implementation of `MatButton` (and a bunch of other stuff).  When you `import {MatButton} from "@angular/material/button"`, it resolves this package file, looks at its `module` and `typings` fields, and uses those to resolve the runtime code and exported types, respectively.

You could do the same thing: `@me/core/package.json` would have `module` and `typings` fields that point to empty files; `@me/core/node/package.json` would point to code for your Node-specific `Foo` class, and `@me/core/web/package.json` would point to code for your browser version of `Foo`.

Comment: Hi, you mean you should setup Webpack for instance to copy those package.json to the right place, eg using the copy plugin?

Comment: If that's your build process, sure.  I think in Angular's case, they actually build each subdirectory as its own project, then have a (presumably Bazel?) build step that copies each component's build artifacts into a tree structure.  The complexity of your build process would be up to you.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following code to the `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  }
}
```

And then you can import the module like this:

```js
import { Foo } from '@me/core/nodejs';
```

If you Don't Want to Touch the `tsconfig.json` you can use the following for the import:

```js
import { Foo } from '@me/core/dist/nodejs';
```

### References

- [Package entry points](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points)
- [Support for NodeJS 12.7+ package exports](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079)
- [A Proposal For Module Resolution](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50152)