# Jest moduleNameMapper and NPM package exports

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, jestjs

I am developing fullstack NPM packages with multiple entrypoints (namely client, server and sometimes tests), using the `exports` property of `package.json`.
I also use a small hack to make TS work with exports until it's officially supported (see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058081/package-json-with-multiple-entrypoints), [this hackish solution](https://blog.mozilla.org/data/2021/04/07/this-week-in-glean-publishing-glean-js/) and [this ticket](https://github.com/VulcanJS/vulcan-npm/issues/80)).

The package.json ends up looking like this:

```json
{
  "name": "@vulcanjs/graphql",
  "version": "0.4.7",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js",
    "./server": "./dist/server/index.js",
    "./testing": "./dist/testing.js"
  },
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "server": [
        "./dist/server/index.d.ts"
      ],
      "testing": [
        "./dist/testing.d.ts"
      ]
    }
  },
  "description": "Vulcan graphQL schema generator",
...
```

You can then import using either `@vulcanjs/graphql` for shared code, and `@vulcanjs/graphql/server` for Node.js-only code.

It works perfect in my Next.js app. However, it seems to break Jest `moduleNameMapper`.

1. First, I had this:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@vulcanjs/(.*)": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/@vulcanjs/$1",
    ],
  },
```

The error is:

```
 Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module @vulcanjs/graphql/server mapped as:
    [
      "/code/vulcan-next/node_modules/@vulcanjs/graphql/server",
    ].
```

The problem is that it tries to find a package named `@vulcanjs/graphql/server`: yet "server" is not a different package, it's an entrypoint of `@vulcanjs/graphql`.

2. I've also tried this:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@vulcanjs/(.*)/(.*)": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/@vulcanjs/$1",
    ],
  },
```

With this config, `@vulcanjs/graphql/server` is mapped to `@vulcanjs/graphql`. The problem is that now, server code is not found. I've checked and the problem is that this solution totally removes the `/server`: so `@vulcanjs/graphql/server` points to the main entrypoints instead of the server entrypoint.

3. Finally I did try to remove the `moduleNameMapper`, but then `@vulcanjs/graphql/server` package is not found by Jest. Note that I need the mapper for a use case I did not demonstrate here, so getting rid of it is possible but not the best solution.

The bug can be reproduced by installing the framework: https://github.com/VulcanJS/vulcan-next. You can clone, `yarn install`, unskip the test in `src/models/tests/sampleModel.server.test.ts` and run `yarn run test:unit sampleModel`. It will show the error.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Seems related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9771