How to bundle "types" field in package.json when using "export" rather than "main"
When using the "main" field of package.json for a Typescript NPM package, this documentation explains how to ship your types (as .d.ts files) alongside the payload exported JS file.
package.json also allows multiple entrypoints, multiple js files, to be specified using the "exports" field rather than "main".
But in that case, how should the various .d.ts files of these various entrypoints be specified in package.json ?

You should show what you have tried and how it didn't work.

@RuanMendes I have no idea what to try : I found no specific documentation of the "types" field anywhere save for the vague information I linked. As far as I know, it only takes a simple string, when I need it not to take an array of strings, but an object matching js files to d.ts files. How do I test that ? How do I know what works on any computer, and even then, how do I know it will keep working in the next node.js version ?

I suggest you paste your question into ChatGPT and try its suggestions. Or look for similar questions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058081/package-json-with-multiple-entrypoints

@RuanMendes ChatGPT does not provide any assurance of support in future versions of node.js, the reason I'm coming here is to have answers I can rely on. And that question does not say how to type the other entrypoints, it only explains what I already said in my second paragraph.

You may specify d.ts file separately for each export option.
This feature appeared in TS 4.7
Example:
// package.json
{
    "name": "my-package",
    "type": "module",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            // Entry-point for `import "my-package"` in ESM
            "import": {
                // Where TypeScript will look.
                "types": "./types/esm/index.d.ts",

                // Where Node.js will look.
                "default": "./esm/index.js"
            },
            // Entry-point for `require("my-package") in CJS
            "require": {
                // Where TypeScript will look.
                "types": "./types/commonjs/index.d.cts",

                // Where Node.js will look.
                "default": "./commonjs/index.cjs"
            },
        }
    },

    // Fall-back for older versions of TypeScript
    "types": "./types/index.d.ts",

    // CJS fall-back for older versions of Node.js
    "main": "./commonjs/index.cjs"
}


Or some real example. From stylelint package:
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./types/stylelint/index.d.mts",
        "default": "./lib/index.mjs"
      },
      "require": {
        "types": "./types/stylelint/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./lib/index.cjs"
      }
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./lib/utils/*": "./lib/utils/*"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.cjs",
  "types": "types/stylelint/index.d.ts",


Thanks a lot ! After testing it seems it's also possible to omit the import/require divide, and put the types/default object directly under the path.
